Local Vol - Time Scale
I am a beginner in derivatives and I am studying the Local Vol formula. My question is related to the time-scale of the volatility found after applying the formula below:
Since W = Sigma^2 * T, I believe the result is related to T (0.50 for 6 months, for example).
In annual terms, do we just multiply the final variance by 1/T?


If $\sigma_{BS}$ is the annual variance and you want the 6 month variance, then you need to divide by the factor, i.e. $\sigma_{6 \text{month}} = \frac{\sigma_{\text{year}}}{\sqrt{2}}$ for 6-months. For the local volatility, it is no different. In the formula, change the annualized Black-Scholes volatility into the increments you want, and change the T into the increments you want. The $w$ won't change ($w = \frac{\sigma^2}{2}(2T)$) since the total variance is basically a normalizing mechanism, but the $y$'s will change since $y=log\left(\frac{K}{Se^{(r-q)T}}\right)$
